# video on a hidden layer shows up in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube, hidden

I have a youtube video embedded on my site.
The video is not started (though it doesn't matter).

I can hide it by setting it's parent div display:none style to show another content in it's place.
Smth like changing from

```
<div>
<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx">
</iframe>
</div>
<div style='display:none;'>
another content
</div>
```

to

```
<div style='display:none;'>
<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx">
</iframe>
</div>
<div>
another content
</div>
```

In Explorer/Firefox it works fine. In Chrome it mostly works, but on some machines (about 20% chromes I tried) the video does hide, but when I move the mouse over it's place (where another content is displayed) square pieces of the video image blink through the content covering it.

I've tried shifting the video to the left in addition to hiding it (style='display:none;left:-9999px;') but it doesn't help, the video blinks in the same place though in Firebug and Chrome DevTools I can see the -9999px style is applied.

On those machines where it happens in Chrome it happens always (and on same machines it works fine in IE/FF). Chrome version is the latest everywhere (it autoupdates), currently it's 27.

What would you suggest?

Comment: You don't have a closing iframe tag. I don't know if that's a typo made when posting the code, but that will cause various rendering issues (depending on the parser it will either try to close the tag immediately, wrap all following content in that iframe, or simply refuse to parse). If that isn't the case then I was unable to reproduce in Chrome 27.0.1453.116 on Windows 8.

Comment: You're right, it's a typo, thanks. It works in FF and IE, and often in Chrome, so it's normal you can't reproduce it. Actually those 2 machines where I saw it do not belong to me that's why I can't quickly test various approaches. But I can change the code and in few days try if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to add **?wmode=opaque** to youtube links. The code

```
<div style='display:none;'>
<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx/?wmode=opaque">
</iframe>
</div>
<div>
another content
</div>
```

hides the video correctly in those chromes it didn't work before.